# Fill the textbox value in angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have working on Edit Profile page in angular Js

Normally List of details will be show. When click on one list , I called the one method

```
 $scope.editContact = function(user){
            $('#editContactSection').show();
            $scope.eUser = user;
        }
```

Then I assigned the text box value by eUser

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname"  ng-model="fname" name="fname" ng-minlength='3' value="{{eUser.firstname}}" required>
                            <div ng-show='editContacForm.fname.$error.minlength' class='error'>Enter atleast 3 characters</div>
```

Here i got the textbox value in input tag in console like value="somename".
Value is assigned correctly. But i can't see in textbox in browser window

And how to change the drop down list value. That drop down list value filled by angular js ng-repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting `ng-model='eUser.firstname'`

as in

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="fname"  ng-model="eUser.firstname" name="fname" ng-minlength='3'  required>
```

Comment: How to change the drop down based on id or value?

Comment: you can set the ng-model for the select tag, refer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$scope.editContact = function(user){
   $('#editContactSection').show();
   $scope.eUser = user;
   $scope.fname = $scope.eUser.firstname;
}
```

Or

```
<input data-ng-init="fname=eUser.firstname" type="text" class="form-control" id="fname"  ng-model="fname" name="fname" ng-minlength='3' required>
                            <div ng-show='editContacForm.fname.$error.minlength' class='error'>Enter atleast 3 characters</div>
```